# findViewById still return null (newbie)

Tags: android

Hello, i'm new to the android(also java) so i try to create some easy app. This app will have one base layout from xml and the dynamic layout which will be create from code and will be insert into that base layout. But when i use the findViewbyId it won't work, it return as null. 
    After that i try to insert "setContentView" before trying findViewbyId and also clean project... and it still got NULL .. 
Here are my code..

```
package com.app.something;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
LinearLayout lLayout;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(this);
    grid.setColumnCount(5);
    for (int i = 0;i<20;i++){
        ImageButton ib = new ImageButton(this);
        ib.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        ib.setId(i+1);
        final int index = i;
        ib.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {   
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("TAG","The index is" + index);
            }
        });
        grid.addView(ib);
    }
    lLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
    if(lLayout == null)Log.i("TAG", "It said, NULLL");
    else {
        lLayout.addView(grid);
        setContentView(lLayout);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

and this is the base layout activity_main (blank)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#ffffff00"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for all comment.. now its work yeah! 
I meant i forgot to add that id and set the same layout also that how to use setcontentview.. thx
I appreciate all of your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firt you are trying to cast a `RelativeLayout` to a `LinearLayout`. Second you missed the id attribute for your `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#ffffff00"
android:id="@+id/myId"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

</LinearLayout>
```

after fix that you can retrieve your layout this way:

```
lLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myId);
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
lLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
```

to

```
RelativeLayout lLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
```

because `activity_main` layout conatin `RelativeLayout` layout as root View instead of  `LinearLayout` and you also need to define `android:id` for RelativeLayout layout.

or you can do it as using `LayoutInflater` :

```
View lLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main);
if(lLayout == null)
  Log.i("TAG", "It said, NULLL");
 else {
      lLayout.addView(grid);
      setContentView(lLayout);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
```

1.you have to pass ID for that view, add `android:id` attribute to relative layout.
2.you dont have any linear layout in your code
3.you have a relative layout cast this to `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 1):

you can not use

```
lLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
```

as per the method name it finds the view By id of the view, not the resource id like you are using. you can access a view by an id that is set by using

```
android:id="@+id/someid"
```

then from code

```
lLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.someid);
```

Answer (score 0):

findViewById searches in your layout, so e.g.:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layout_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#ffffff00"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

The you can use it:

```
(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_main);
```